# How to set an attribute to a vector in rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

How to add attributes to vectors in python with rpy2.
As an example how can I reproduce this R code:

```
library(evir)
pot<-c(2.0,3.2,4,5,6,7)
ts<-c(1,6,7,19,20,30)
attr(pot,"times")<-ts
output<-decluster(pot,run=2)
```

I can't find any help after searching several hours on the net.
I guess Laurent has the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute `slots`. What is described about it in the doc for S4 objects applies to attributes (http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/notebooks/s4class.html).

Here it should work with:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector, IntVector
pot = FloatVector((2.0, 3.2, 4, 5, 6, 7))
ts = IntVector((1,6,7,19,20,30))
pot.slots['times'] = ts
```

For rpy2 < 2.7, you should use do_slot_assign :

```
pot.do_slot_assign("times",ts)
```

Comment: `pip install rpy2 --upgrade`

Comment: It is not so easy on my system ;-) Could you specify the minimum version needed in the answer? Thx

Comment: Probably 2.7.0. On older versions do_slot_assign might get you there.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (`.slots`) did not work for me for SexpVectors (`'ListSexpVector' object has no attribute 'slots'` or `'IntSexpVector' object has no attribute 'slots'`, etc). A workaround I found was to extract the setter from the base environment and use it directly:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
assign_attr = base._env['attr<-']
d = assign_attr(d, 'nodePar', value=myvalue)
```

Importantly, the setter does not modify the original variable, so you need to re-assign the vector.